# Twitter Bootstrap modal Issue 531

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/531

I am using Twitter Boostrap with the fix described in issue 531 to allow the use of the data attribute to pass data to modals and this works ok but...

```
$('#modal2').data('modal').options.user_id
```

seems to be different to:

```
$('#modal2').data('user_id')
```

I am passing a user_id:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-user_id="5" href="#modal2">Edit Picture</a>

$('#modal2').on('show', function (event) {
    $('#modal2').data('user_id', $('#modal2').data('modal').options.user_id );
});
```

But I am also trying to pass the same data attribute from one modal to another:

inside #modal1:

```
$('#modal1').modal('hide');
$('#modal2').data('user_id', 6); // successfully sets the user_id to 6
$('#modal2').modal('show');
```

The problem is when modal2 is opened using this method it has the incorrect value (5 instead of 6) and seems to be ignoring the data set by $('#modal2').data('user_id', 6);

How can I progmatically set the value of data('modal').options.user_id or is this a bug with the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different. The patch for passing data in Bootstrap Modals only transfers the data from the originating anchor to the `Modal.options` object.  So,

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-user_id="5" href="#modal2">Edit Picture</a>
```

gives you:

```
$('#modal2').data('modal').options.user_id === 5 // true
```

but this does not add a new data object to the modal element.

So, in your case, trying to assign a value to a separate data object (`data('user_id')`) will have no effect on the `Modal.options.user_id` value.

You either need to manipulate the data value on the originating anchor, or manipulate the `Modal.options.user_id` value directly.

Comment: What then, is the syntax to manipulate the data value of Modal.options.user_id directly?

Comment: `$('#modal2').data('modal').options.user_id = "some_value"`

Comment: Thanks, nothing is usually ever that simple :)